# Infinite right scrolling recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a weird problem in which when scrolling right in my horizontal recycler view the scrolling is infinite while the presented items are presented in loops.

That is i have 15 items, when the 15th item is shown scrolling right show the first item and so on...

That could be vary cool but its not my intention, also when trying to scroll left it dont get back from the first item to the 15th

This started to happen when i changed the recycler view width from "match_parent" to a view inside a linear layout with weights:

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/appTrailersTV"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">
            <!--android:background="@color/antique_white"-->

            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/appTraliersRV"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

this is the code for the recycler view:

```
        myAppsRV.setAdapter(myAppsdapter);
        LinearLayoutManager myAppsllm = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        myAppsRV.setLayoutManager(myAppsllm);
```

What i actually want is the scrolling to end at the last item

When tracing the logs of the scrolling listener it shows that the index of the visible view is showing the proper index 1-14 and when reaching 15 its switches back to 1:

```
appTraliersRV.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            Log.i(Utils.TAG, "appTrailersMoreTV index: " + (((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition() +1));
            if ((((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition() +1)== AppResources.trailersVideos.size()) {
                appTrailersMoreTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                appTrailersMoreTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post the adapter code too.

Comment: @danypata The adapter class is quite big, also when setting the "match_parent" the view acts normally without touching the adapter code